# Getting error while trying to stream data using python 2.7 and tweepy

Tags: python, import

I am trying to stream data using tweepy but getting error 
ImportError: No module named tweepy
 i have tried to uninstall and reinstall tweepy and installed it using pip and pip3 as well

I am using ubuntu 16.04LTS

Code used is:-

```
from tweepy import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream

 #Variables that contains the user credentials to access Twitter API 
 api_key = ""
 api_secret = ""
 access_token_key = ""
 acess_token_secret = ""



  class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
    print data
    return True

def on_error(self, status):
    print status


if __name__ == '__main__':

l = StdOutListener()
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
stream = Stream(auth, l)

'python', 'javascript', 'ruby'
stream.filter(track=['python', 'javascript', 'ruby'])
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are using?

Comment: @JonathanPorter sir the code has been edited please have a look

Comment: it sounds like you have multiple versions of python and aren't using the version you installed tweepy on. Add the following to your code and check your assumptions: `import sys` 
`print sys.version `

Comment: @JonathanPorter this was the ouput   2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]